# Has anyone tried transfering 0.00000001 BTC (the currently minimum amount) successfully?

Tags: mtgox, satoshi

I did an experiment of withdrawing 0.00000001 BTC from MtGox. And this transaction still cannot be seen on http://blockexplorer.com/ after about an hour.

---

Concern solved, thank you everybody!

http://blockexplorer.com/address/1Mm1YSodmgoDEHEQtQaZLjBW8Nemje3kFw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I have successfully transferred 0.00000001 BTC (commonly referred to as a Satoshi) before.

What is possible within the scope of a MtGox withdrawal is another question entirely. MtGox uses a custom client and has a fee structure and other assorted math to contend with that may not allow for such a transfer at present. If your withdrawal has not appeared in Block Explorer you should contact MtGox support as it may reflect more on their modified system than the default behavior of Bitcoin.

Comment: Maybe you can link to that transaction as a reference?

Comment: The 0.00000001 BTC is received after five hours.

Comment: @ThePiachu Here you go, http://blockexplorer.com/address/1Mm1YSodmgoDEHEQtQaZLjBW8Nemje3kFw